# Cannot log into wso2 carbon when deploying WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 on linux server

Tags: linux, centos, wso2, esb

I have uploaded WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 into a linux server and I can run the esb. But the problem is even I enter the default user name and password (admin, admin). unable to logged in. and it is giving an error saying username and password is incorrect. But in the carbon log I can see loggedin as admin@admin.com.Like when i logged in properly.

Comment: admin@admin.com? Have you tried to login by a super tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem. I have installed wso2 esb inside my user folder. I relocated it inside shared folder out side user accounts (home/esb). then it works fine.

Comment: This explanation does not seems realistic. Deployed location is not important for the WSO2 products when running. If you uploaded a pack which was running in your local machine to the linux server, then this can be most probably due to a permission problem in file system.